# i have some problems with constraints

Tags: ios, swift

```
retweetButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: replyButton.trailingAnchor, constant: actionSpacing),
        retweetButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: replyButton),
```

warning: Cannot convert value of type 'UIButton' to expected argument type 'NSLayoutAnchor'

what's problem

Comment: `equalTo: replyButton` this bit

Comment: retweetButton.centerYAnchor can't equal replyButton because one is a y Anchor and one is a Button

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an **NSLayoutAnchor** here. If you check equalTo parameter, it is expecting a NSLayoutAnchor

> retweetButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: **NSLayoutAnchor**)

you are passing a UIButton.
That's why it's giving you the error and error description is simple and straight forward.

Simply pass an NSLayoutAnchor accroding to your need where you want to place your button.
Here in this case simply put centre Y anchor of replyButton error will go away. you can change this any anchor you want.

> retweetButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: replyButton.centerYAnchor)

Answer (score 0):

```
  retweetButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: replyButton.trailingAnchor, constant: actionSpacing)
    
retweetButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: replyButton.centerYAnchor)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.